# Player Name is not getting synced in unity multiplayer

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development, multiplayer

- Names are not getting synced for players across network.

Here is the code for syncing names -:

```
[SerializeField] private TMPro.TextMeshPro nameForThePlayer;   
private NetworkVariable<FixedString64Bytes> playerName = new NetworkVariable<FixedString64Bytes>();

private void OnEnable()
{
    playerName.OnValueChanged += playerNameHandler;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    playerName.OnValueChanged -= playerNameHandler;
}


public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
{
    if (!IsOwner) { return; }

    if (IsHost)
    {
        SyncNames(NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId);
    }
    else
    {
        RequestSyncNamesServerRpc(NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId);
    }

}

[ServerRpc]
public void RequestSyncNamesServerRpc(ulong clientId)
{
    SyncNames(clientId);
}

private void SyncNames(ulong _clientId)
{
    PlayerData? data = ServerGameNetPortal.GetassignedDataForClient(_clientId);
    playerName.Value = data.Value.GetPlayerName;
}

private void playerNameHandler(FixedString64Bytes previousValue, FixedString64Bytes newValue)
{
    nameForThePlayer.text = newValue.ToString();
}
```

- Using `Update` instead of `OnNetworkSpawn` works but I don't want to do it in update as the names should  only be synced during connecting only.

**EDIT**

```
public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
{
    if (!IsOwner)
    {
        RequestSyncNamesServerRpc(OwnerClientId);
    }
    if (IsHost)
    {
        SyncNames(NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId);
    }

}

[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
public void RequestSyncNamesServerRpc(ulong clientId)
{
    SyncNames(clientId);
}
```

- The above code works fine but in `OnNetworkSpawn` why are we checking it for other clients **In the `!isOwner` block** as network variable's value gets replicated for every other object spawning beside our object.Right?

---

Comment: Is there any harm in `SyncNames` being called multiple times? i.e. Could you use `Awake` or `Start` instead?

Comment: Hello @Absinthe I tried using awake and start but still names are not syncing.